# Assigning color to the region outside of roi in image in opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, roi

I have to make the outside region of roi as black color. I have been stucking with this for days! Thanks in advance :-)
In the below image I want to make the region outside the rectangle as black color, so how it can be done using opencv ?

[roi in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcPak.png)

Comment: You seem to have omitted your image, your code and your ROI...

Comment: Hi. As Mark said could you please provide us with your image, your code and your  Region Of Interest. This will make it easier for us to answer the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).